# Postgresql dies with 235 + concurrent connections

Tags: postgresql

I have installed postgresql on an Azure VM and am running tests to see if postgresql can support the expected load.  I have increased the max_connections value to 1000 but when I run ab -c 300, postgresql stops responding.  Are there any other settings I should be changing?
Thanks, Kate.

Comment: You need to add a connection pooling tool like pgbouncer. Postgres is not built to handle 100+ connections.

Comment: To be fair, PostgreSQL can handle 100 connections, but if they all start doing something at the same time you're going to want 100 CPU cores to deal with it.

Comment: I think you will need to be more specific than "dies" if you want detailed help. What exactly happens?

Comment: Igor Romachenko, you were dead on :) Here is an interesting read on how Instagram uses PostgreSQL http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/13649370142/what-powers-instagram-hundreds-of-instances-dozens-of

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL will perform best with a lot less than 1000 connections on most hardware. Usually less than 100. If your application cannot queue work using a connection pool, you should put an external connection pool like PgBouncer between your application and PostgreSQL.

See: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections